# WP 8 , cannot use USB connection to connect to internet via phone

Tags: 8.0, internet-sharing

I bought a Lumia 620 considering that the MS guys would give some comp to Google but seems I'm let down here

The feature to connect to Internet using the USB cable via the phone is not available in WP8, the Wi fi sharing disconnects every two minutes or so (not sure how long it is made to stay connected)

Really frustrating. Been making a list of features that are missing.

Anyone got a fix to enable the above feature?

Comment: You need to elaborate on what specifically you are looking to fix. As it stands, your question is vague.

Answer (score 3):

Wifi is disconnecting is not a bug but a feature to save battery. there are some apps that keep your wifi alive but it's not in the OS currently. Also when the phone is connected to the power cable it will keep the wifi alive.

wifi will automatically reconnect when you start using the phone.

Internet sharing works through WIFI only and not via cable: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L33DUS3Kqg4

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8 can keep the WiFi all the time, it is under Settings | WiFi. It is off by default.

If this is on and your phone is still disconnecting, does it happen on all WiFi networks? If so, a hard reset might be in order.

Comment: I believe he's asking about using the phone as a mobile hotspot, so things are connecting to it...