# Is it possible to use internet over USB to pc from Lumia?

Tags: 8.1, internet-sharing, nokia-lumia-820, usb

I want to share my mobile internet to my pc through USB cable.
I have Lumia 820 and OS is Windows phone 8.1

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/2431/106